# Find Largest Cell Values in Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out a formula to find the largest values of a column and then use the value of a second and third column basically to solve a tie, and then display the persons name associated to that data in a different cell.

I've provided an image with test data to try to illustrate what I need:

[image: example data]

To the right of the orange boxes shows the top 5 people based on the Criteria I want to use Basically I want Box 1 to display whatever person has the highest value in field K, followed by the second highest in box 2, etc. If the value in box K is identical I want the Value in the Total column to act as a tie breaker, if that still doesn't break the tie I want to use column I as the final tie breaker.

Obviously I want to leave the sorting in the table as is and the values within the table will change regularly (so copying all the data to a secondary data sheet manually to use sort functions won't work unless that process can be automated).

I've tried variations of VLOOKUP, INDEX, and MAX functions without any luck.

Comment: Hi; are you open to VBA as a solution for this? Or are you wanting to keep it strictly formula based without relying on macros? If the latter, https://superuser.com might be more appropriate than Stack Overflow.

Comment: You may want to share what you tried and where you got stuck or got the furthest with your VLOOKUP, INDEX or MAX approaches

Comment: Depending on how involved the VBA portion is I'm open too it, but I'd prefer to stay as close as possible to formulas, but I found various other excel questions posted on this site without VBA involved

Basically using VLOOKUP I was able to find the largest and second largest values in K using an embedded large function, but was unable to distinguish the two tied for third by using the total function.

Index as well didn't have any thing I could find that would use the Total column as a tie breaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all values are non-negative integers, you can make a new column with the score you want to maximize, one that is a formula involving K, J, and I:

L1:

```
=(K1*(MAX(J:J)+1)+J1)*(MAX(I:I)+1)+I1
```

Repeat that down column L, then use RANK() and VLOOKUP() as normal to select the winner and runners-up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Do you mind explaining how the math in the formula works? I want to make sure that  The Total Column and the I column don't ever allow a column with a lower value in the K Column to be higher than a higher value in the K column if that makes sense. Using test data it seems to work though.

Comment: Sure. It's a little easier to see if you replace the MAX(...)+1 bits with 1000: `=(K1*(1000)+J1)*(1000)+I1` Then you get a number that looks like NNN million, MMM thousand, and PPP, where NNN is the number from column K, MMM is the number from column J and PPP is the number from column I. Using MAX(col)+1 makes more efficient use of the number space as well as seamlessly handling the cases involving entries greater than 999.

Comment: I still don't get how it is taking into account all 3 columns the way I want to, but I put it into my actual database and I am not seeing any errors. Its seems to pull the exact same data when using a test sort prioritizing K, then Total, Then I. So it is working exactly the way I want it to. So thanks

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it: Each point (i.e., each step of size 1) in column K is multiplied by a value one larger than the largest value in column J. So if the largest value in J is 620, then values in K map like: 0 -> 0, 1 -> 621, 2 -> 1242, 3 -> 1863, etc. So then when you add in J, the J value fits in the gap between this K and "one more than this K". It can't jump the next value of K. Then you repeat the process for this new sum and the next column, column I.